# VirtualBox upgrade: E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: windows-vista, virtualbox

I just tried upgrading VirtualBox from 3.1.something to 4.0.6 on my Windows Vista (ultimate, 64-bit) host.  I did the installation under an Administrator account.  Now I'm trying to use it from a different account, and I get:

> Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.
>   The application will now terminate.
>   Details
>   Callee RC: E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005)

Running VirtualBox from the Administrator account works fine.

Is there a workaround for this?  Is there a way to run VirtualBox from my normal user account?

Is there a way to find out exactly what it's unable to get access to?  As I have an Administrator account here, I should be able to grant any necessary permissions to my user account, if I know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try the right-click "[Use as administrator](http://vistasupport.mvps.org/run_as_administrator.htm)" option?

You'll have to introduce the user and password of an user with administration privileges.

hope it works ;D